# HttpClient 4.1, InputStreamEntity, automatically calculated length

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

In [HttpClient 3.1](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/InputStreamRequestEntity.html) we had

```
InputStreamRequestEntity.CONTENT_LENGTH_AUTO
   // The content length will be calculated automatically.
```

How can I achieve the same effect in 4.1 for InputStreamEntity?

Answer (score 3):

You can put -1 as length if you deal with HTTP 1.1. It will switch to (more efficient) chunked encoding where you don't have to specify the content length explicitly; plus you gain other benefits in addition.

You can check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding for more details on the chunked encoding.

Answer (score -1):

You can't 'cos they messed up the API completely in the new version. What that used to do was buffer the whole stream into a byte array in memory, so now you just do that yourself and use a ByteArrayEntity instead.

Look at the original code here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/java/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/InputStreamRequestEntity.java?view=markup

line 125 onwards.

The whole API is like that now, all the ease of use is gone. Maybe it is better, more safe implementation but it is horrible API.